# Using @async @sync macros to improve performance

Tags: multithreading, performance, julia, task

I'm trying to parallelize this function by using @async @sync

```
function INSR_opt(f)
    function INSR0_opt(seq)
        len = length(seq)
        res = seq[end]
        @inbounds @sync for i in range(len-2,step=-1,stop=0)
            @async res = f([seq[i+1], res])
        end
        return res
    end
    return INSR0_opt
end
```

The way I'm using the macros seems correct to me but the performance just gets worse
Without the macros:

```
122.962 μs (1073 allocations: 69.00 KiB)
```

With the macros:

```
154.681 μs (1091 allocations: 69.95 KiB)
```

I've even tried using @spawn instead of @async but the performance still won't improve. I've checked the number of threads running with `Threads.nthreads()` and they are 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is sequential, as you have a recursive dependence in `res` - so trying to parallelize it is both not possible and can lead to incorrect results. Essentially your code tries to re-implement `foldr` in a less efficient and non-generic way:

```
julia> INSR_opt(((a, b),) -> a => b)(1:4)
1 => (2 => (3 => 4))

julia> foldr(=>, 1:4)
1 => (2 => (3 => 4))
```